# How to dynamically regulate voltage from a DC power supply to motors

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, dc, voltage-divider

I'm currently trying to take an approximately 12V, 2 to 3 Amp, LiPO battery and dynamically (using either a microcontroller or a good old fashioned dial/slider) adjust the voltage it is supplying to a pair of hobby motors, probably bottoming out at around 5 or 6 volts, but being able to go lower wouldn't be a problem.

I've read a bit about voltage dividers, but it seems that it might not be the best way to go?

This question might be a bit obvious and for this I apologize, my knowledge of circuitry is pretty barebones. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to use a voltage regulator and if your motor current is 1.5 amps max then I would recommend using a buck voltage regulator like this: -

[image]

You can vary the output voltage with the resistor potential divider that feeds the FB pin. Power efficiency remains about 90% for a good range of loads and you will never get anything like this from a potential divider and, a potential divider would never give you a regulated output voltage.

If you need more current then this might be attractive to you: -

[image]

There is a version of the LT8610 that has an FB pin so you can set the output voltage. You pay for what you get and if you want good performance you need to pay a few dollars more.

Comment: +1. All people recommend PWM, but DC motors just like DC better. And for small motors it's simple to implement with buck converters nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

> I've read a bit about voltage dividers, but it seems that it might not be the best way to go?

You are correct. Since the motor does not present a constant resistance the potential divider won't provide a constant voltage but will vary with speed and load.

The most common technique is to use pulse-width modulation. In your case full power is applied to the motor but only for part of the time. For example, if you want 40% voltage you could switch the supply on for 4 ms and off for 6 ms. You choose the frequency to be fast enough that the inertia of the motor keeps it going between pulses and, perhaps, doesn't create any audible noise.

See [Electronics Tutorials](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/blog/pulse-width-modulation.html) for what looks like a good introduction and a simple 555 timer circuit to get you started.